# Writing Text and Binary to the Same File

Tags: c#, arrays, filestream, streamwriter

I'm having trouble figuring out how to switch between StreamWriter to write out text and FileStream to dump a byte[] into a file.

I'm using StreamWriter to manually write out an XML in text (there are reasons I'm not using XMLWriter).  In two sections, a byte[] array needs to be dumped into the file (TIF image).  I know if can somehow be done because I'm trying to mimic a file we get from our vendor.  I was trying to just use the StreamWriter and convert the byte[] to a string using ISO-8859-1, but there are some additional characters that get put it that make it an invalid TIF.

Am I overthinking this?  Do I need to close the StreamWriter, reopen the file and append using the FileStream, the close and reopen with StreamWriter to write additional text?

edit:  OK, this almost works.  The binary portion is now fine, but all of the text portion has 0x00 in between each character.

```
            using (System.IO.FileStream fileST = new System.IO.FileStream(filenameST, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                string z;
                fileST.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(z =""), 0, z.Length);
                fileST.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(z =partID), 0, z.Length);
                fileST.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(z ="Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8"), 0, z.Length);
                fileST.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(z ="Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"), 0, z.Length);
                fileST.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(z ="Content-Id: <" + contentID + ">"), 0, z.Length);
                fileST.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(z =""), 0, z.Length);
//truncated
                fileST.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(z =imagekey + "00FBW"), 0, z.Length);// + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Miscellaneous.MiscTools.GEncheckImageFront(outputPath, font)), 0, z.Length);
                fileST.Write(aFrontImage, 0, aFrontImage.Length);
}
```

Where aFrontImage is the byte[] of the tif file.

The original code was:

```
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter fileST = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filenameST))
            {
                string partID = "------=_Part_" + partline1 + "_" + partline2 + ".0" + XMLdata[i, 0].GetLast(4) + XMLdata[i, 3].GetLast(5) + "321";
                string contentID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper();
                fileST.WriteLine("");
                fileST.WriteLine(partID);
                fileST.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
                fileST.WriteLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                fileST.WriteLine("Content-Id: <" + contentID + ">");
                fileST.WriteLine("");
```

Comment: You could use Base 64 encoding for the binary data

Comment: Another option might be to use only FileStream and manually encode the text portion into a byte[] before writing

Comment: @Alex - Unfortunately that won't work (though I tried).  Our application reads in the data and expects the binary byte array to be there.  I'm writing a tool to create test files, but I can't impact the translator code that reads the files in.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - that may be an option.  Is there anything like .ToByteArray I could use on a string inline with fs?

Comment: Yes, see Zer0's answer

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is probably outputting it in UTF-16, you probably want  UTF8 which is `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: UTF8 helped, but I've noticed one other major setback - changing from WriteLine with the StreamWrite to Write with the FileStream also doesn't result in newline being generated.

Comment: Also encode `Environment.NewLine` where you want them.

Comment: In the end, it turned out easier to open and close the file and switch between StreamWriter and FileStream.  Using just StreamWriter, there was no feasible way of writing the binary data, using just FileStream, the XML always came back invalid regardless of encoding.

Thank everyone for all of your helpful answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert your string and write all bytes to the file.  Depending on your encoding you can do something like this:

`bytes[] stringAsBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myString)`

Comment: Ok, so I have a lot of lines being written like:

'fileST.WriteLine("   <businessDate>" + XMLdata[i, 4].Insert(6, "-").Insert(4, "-") + "</businessDate>");'

I tried just wrapping the Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() around those and changing to a filestream using fileST.WriteAllBytes, but that didn't actually work (invalid arguments).

Is there a way to wrap that around without converting each line to a string for presentation?

Comment: @JesseWilliams I'm not sure I understand where you're getting invalid arguments from.  Can you post the code you tried to use in your question?